Playwright - select element that is not child of another element
With Playwright, how can I select an element which is NOT a descendant of another element?
I have two almost identical elements of which I'm only interested in one. It's difficult to define a locator that selects only the one I need, but the one that I don't need is a child of another element that I can easily select. It this possible to do?

Can you show a sample structure, please? Provide as much context as you can, because there may be a better way to select it than you may assume.

As per @ggorlen's comment, a specific, simplified example of your scenario would be very helpful. There are a number of different strategies you might use and they have different trade-offs in long-term reliability. Here is a jsfiddle and a Playwright test to identify the first button within it using 3 different methods.
    import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
    
    test('test', async ({ page }) => {
      await page.goto('https://jsfiddle.net/c2o0u68n/');
      await page.frameLocator('iframe[name="result"]').getByRole('button', { name: 'Twin buttons' }).first().highlight();  //first match
      await page.frameLocator('iframe[name="result"]').locator(':above(div#easyToFind > button)').getByRole("button", { name: 'Twin buttons' }).highlight(); //higher than the other one
      await page.frameLocator('iframe[name="result"]').locator('div > div:not(#easyToFind)').getByRole("button", { name: 'Twin buttons' }).highlight(); //not inside the other one
    });

The first one just accepts there will be several matching selectors and gets the first one. Will your item always be the first/last/nth? If not then this is flaky.
The second one finds the button because it's above the item you can identify easily. This could easily break if the screen size changes and the site has a responsive design.
The third one specifies that the button is inside a div which isn't the one you can identify. Using the CSS locators isn't great (this is just a quick example) but your element might have a cleaner method available, such as locator.filter({hasNot: page.locator('blah')})
